# Porque me aparece siempre que inicio la activity el array vacio?

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos

Estoy trabajando con una BD rom o DAo cada uno la llama de una manera. Es una lista de la compra con 2 activity 1 un reciclerView y otra para añadir. Al iniciar la app la idae es que verifique si hay algo en la BD o en el array del recicler, si hay pues la inicia y si no pues se va a la activity de añadir. El problmea es que aun habiendo productos me dice que no los hay. Os dejo el codigo.
Este es el Main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 10;
private RecyclerView rv1;
private AdaptadorProducto adaptador;
private List<Producto> datos = new ArrayList<>();
private Context contexto;
private ListaCompraViewModel listaCompraViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    contexto = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listaCompraViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ListaCompraViewModel.class);
    rv1 = findViewById(R.id.rv1);
    adaptador = new AdaptadorProducto(this, datos);
    rv1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    rv1.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv1.setAdapter(adaptador);
    registerForContextMenu(rv1);
    listaCompraViewModel.getProductos().observe(this, adaptador::setDatos);
    if (datos.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "La lista de la compra esta vacia le enviamos a la opcion de añadir",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, NuevoProductoActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int posicion = -1;
    try {
        posicion = adaptador.getPosicion();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.mi1:
            Snackbar.make(this.rv1, "Se ha elegido borrar el elemento " + posicion, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            Producto p = adaptador.getDatos().get(posicion);
            new borrarProducto(BaseDatosApp.getInstance(contexto)).execute(p);
            adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (datos.isEmpty()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogo1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                dialogo1.setTitle("Infornacion");
                dialogo1.setMessage("La lista de la compra esta vacia añada un producto o salga de la aplicacion");
                dialogo1.setCancelable(false);
                dialogo1.setPositiveButton("Añadir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                        añadir();
                    }
                });
                dialogo1.setNegativeButton("Salir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                dialogo1.show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.mi2:
            añadir();
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

public void añadir() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NuevoProductoActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        Producto nProducto = (Producto) data.getExtras().getSerializable("Producto");
        new insertarProducto(BaseDatosApp.getInstance(contexto)).execute(nProducto);
        View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "Se ha insertado un nuevo registro.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
        snackbar.show();
    }
}
```

}

class borrarProducto extends AsyncTask {
    private final BaseDatosApp database;

```
public borrarProducto(BaseDatosApp database) {
    this.database = database;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(final Producto... params) {
    database.productoDAO().delete(params[0]);
    return null;
}
```

}

class insertarProducto extends AsyncTask {
    private final BaseDatosApp database;

```
public insertarProducto(BaseDatosApp database) {
    this.database = database;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(final Producto... params) {
    database.productoDAO().insertAll(params);
    return null;
}
```

La BD

```
@Database(entities = {Producto.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
```

public abstract class BaseDatosApp extends RoomDatabase {
    private static BaseDatosApp INSTANCIA;

```
public static BaseDatosApp getInstance(Context context) {
    if (INSTANCIA == null) {
        INSTANCIA = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.getApplicationContext(),
                BaseDatosApp.class,
                "dbCompra")
                .build();
    }
    return INSTANCIA;
}

public static void destroyInstance() {
    INSTANCIA = null;
}

public abstract ProductoDAO productoDAO();
```

Esta esta relacionada con el recicler

```
 ListaCompraViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private final LiveData<List<Producto>> productos;
public ListaCompraViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    productos = BaseDatosApp
            .getInstance(application)
            .productoDAO().getAll();
}
public LiveData<List<Producto>> getProductos() {
    return productos;
}
```

}

y no se si necesitais alguna clase mas, tengo la adaptadora, los dao

Comment: Por lo que veo tú verificas `if (datos.isEmpty()) {` pero realmente no agregas nada a `datos` en ningún momento. No sé si lo que hay que verificar es `listaCompraViewModel` ¿?

Comment: Pero ya tiene un dato de la vez anterior que use la app osea que datos si tiene, con lo cual no deveria de decir que esta vacio porque entiendo que el array se carga con la base de datos. Como verifico listaCompraViewModel no veoninguna opcion

Comment: Podrías por ejemplo dotar a `ListaCompraViewModel` de un método que sirva para verificar si hay datos en la BD, algo como `hasData()` que verifique mediante una consulta si hay datos devolviendo `true` en ese caso o `false`. Luego, según ese método pasas a llenar el RecyclerView o a hacer otra cosa.

Comment: El problema es que no se implementar las consultas select solo añadir o borrar no me han enseñado otra cosa jaj

Comment: ¿Esto es un ejercicio? ¿Tienes prohibición de usar `SELECT`?

Comment: no no esta prohibido simplemente no se usarlo osea el codigo como ponerlo, La consulta es clara select count(cantidad) from Producto. Por ejemplo si es mayor que 0 pues true y listo, pro no se donde hacerla ni como

Comment: Oh ya. Eso está explicado con mucha claridad en la doc de Android y además creo que está en español. Mira ahí y trata de implementarlo. Si tienes errores puedes plantearlos aquí. No puedo hablarte con más propiedad porque aún no he usado Room (lo tengo pendiente para dar persistencia a una App que maneja una enorme cantidad de tablas) pero no he programado por el momento nada basado en Room.

Comment: Te viene como hacer la consula pero no como llamarla en el main lo he estado leyendo

Comment: Eso es algo básico de POO, no de Android ni de Room. Como dije antes, imagina que en `ListaCompraViewModel` creas un nuevo método que verifica si hay datos en la BD mediante un `SELECT`, simplemente en el main creas la instancia de `ListaCompraViewModel` e invocas ese método, no hay más misterio. Entonces en el main harías algo así: `listaCompraViewModel=new ListaCompraViewModel();  if ( listaCompraViewModel.hasData() ) { //hay datos, llenar el Recycler } else { //No hay datos, hacer otra cosa }` Esto es más o menos una idea.